# How to use list of images to display in ImageView android without using ListView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hi all I don't want to use Listview. I created custom layout for xml. So how to assign list of all image url to display in ImageView?

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class CoverflowSwipe extends Activity {
ImageView images;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
private int position;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.coverflow);
  images=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.launch);
  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras !=null) {
        String[] value = extras.getStringArray(ListActivity.KEY); // here i can get 10 images
         imageLoader.DisplayImage(value[position], images); 
        // but here it displays only one image. how to display all images to set in imageview?

  }

 }
```

}

Comment: You can't display multiple images in a single `ImageView`..

Comment: will you please say why not possible? but we can create dynamic multiple imageview right? @akash93 if multiple imageview dynamically can create means, why not assigning urls in imageview by creating dynamic imageview not possible? i don't know how to proceed. i couldn't get exact one to proceed.

Comment: Yes you can create a multiple imageview by code using loop and can dynamically set the parameter using LayoutParams.

Comment: will you please describe how to proceed? i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple ImageViews to display multiple images..
Yes you can add ImageViews dynamically but you'll need to loop over your url array. Something on the following lines.

```
for(String url:values){
  ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
  LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  image.setLayoutParams(lparams);
  parentLayout.addView(image);
  imageLoader.DisplayImage(url,image);
}
```

`parentLayout` is a reference to the parent layout of the ImageViews

Comment: sorry. can't get you.object parentLayout means the imageview placed inside the layout?